# How to find repetitive values per groups using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find repetitions between rows based on the column. I've tried window functions with row_number() / rank() but they group all the values that are found (similar to GROUP BY) which I do not expect.
How can I find repetitions of the values?

I tried to do something like this:

`SELECT *, rank() OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY id) FROM customers ORDER BY id`

And got the following result:

| id | customer | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | customer_1 | 1 |
| 2 | customer_2 | 1 |
| 3 | customer_2 | 2 |
| 4 | customer_1 | 2 |
| 5 | customer_3 | 1 |
| 6 | customer_1 | 3 |

What I want to do:

| id | customer | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | customer_1 | 1 |
| 2 | customer_2 | 1 |
| 3 | customer_2 | 2 |
| 4 | customer_1 | 1 |
| 5 | customer_3 | 1 |
| 6 | customer_1 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for counts within adjacent rows.  This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can define the adjacent rows with the difference of `row_numbers()` and then enumerate them:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer, seqnum - seqnum_2 ORDER BY id) as ranking
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY id) as seqnum_2
      FROM customers c
     ) c
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is it really must be that complicated query? Problem seemed much easier that it is :)

Comment: @Jora . . . This is not particularly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE repeatitions(id, customer, repeat_count) AS (
  SELECT id, customer, 1 as repeat_count
  FROM customers
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.customer, r.repeat_count + 1
  FROM customers c, repeatitions r
  WHERE c.id = r.id + 1 AND c.customer = r.customer
)
SELECT id, customer, repeat_count
FROM repeatitions
ORDER by id
```

I created a [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jAeVyyYUtpSKMXvsFuqoYB/0) to demonstrate it.